# Why is the last element not appending to my array of digits?

Tags: c

Hi I am new to "C" I have a question on some output I got.

The number we are working with as data is: [**4003600000000014**].
I have every element appended to this array except for one I am not sure how to get the last number to print.

I am curious about the number **6422180** I am not sure what it is can someone explain.

[image: OUTPUT]

```
// This is an example of Luhn's algorithm.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_CRED_LEN 16

// Function prototypes.
void payment_method();

int main(void)
{   
    payment_method();
    return 0;
}

long long int get_credit_card_num()
/*
    Gets the users credit card number.
*/
{
    long long int d;

    do
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter in your credit card number: ");
        if (scanf("%lld", &d) == 1)
        {
            printf("\nYour credit card number: (%lld)\n%s", d,
                "------------------------\n\n");
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\tINVALID INPUT CHARACTER ENTERED PLEASE TRY AGAIN!\n%s",
                "\t*************************************************");
            fflush(stdin); // Clear input buffer of any characters!
            get_credit_card_num(); // Start the function again to prompt user.
        }
    } while (d < 0);

    return d;
}

int num_of_ccdigits()
/*
    Counts the amount of digits the user entered. Then compares the number of
    digits to a specific length offered by cardholders they are 13, 15, and 16
    digits long.
*/
{
    long long int cc_num = get_credit_card_num();
    int digits = 0, arr[MAX_CRED_LEN];

    // Count how many digits the user entered then compare the length.
    while (cc_num != 0)
    {
        cc_num /= 10;
        arr[digits] = cc_num % 10;
        digits++;
    }
    // Display the number of digits that the user entered.
    printf("\nNumber of digits: [%i]", digits);
    int a = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < digits; i++)
    {
        printf("\n[%d]:\tYOUR DIGIT ARRAY: %i", a, arr[i - 1]);
        ++a;
    }
    printf("\n\nARRAY WITHOUT LINE BREAKS: %i", arr);
    // Check to see if this is a valid credit card number or a supported one.
    if ((digits != 13) && (digits != 15) && (digits != 16))
    {
        printf("\n\tMUST BE AT LEAST 13, 15, AS HIGH AS 16 DIGITS.\n%s",
            "\t**********************************************\n");
        // if no 13, 15, or 16 digits long restart loop.
        num_of_ccdigits();
    }

    return digits; // return the amount of digits in the credit card number.
}

void payment_method()
{
    int num_of_digits = num_of_ccdigits();

}
```

Comment: Please do NOT post pictures of text. Please DO copy and paste the text into your question (with each line indented by 4-spaces so it formats correctly). Instead of a simple `500 bytes` of text, your .png image requires `13251 bytes` to store.

Comment: Your functions are also unnecessarily recursive.  On invalid entry, you should reiterate the loop, not call the function again.

Comment: @BraidenGole - you don't get it. I'm just trying to help you. Do it your way, but don't be surprised if you get similar, not quite as diplomatic, comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few issues here. For your first question, the code is indexing out of bounds of `arr`, causing undefined behavior:

```
for (i = 0; i < digits; i++)
{
    printf("\n[%d]:\tYOUR DIGIT ARRAY: %i", a, arr[i - 1]);
    ++a;
}
```

On the first iteration, `i = 0` and we proceed to index into `arr[0 - 1]` or `arr[-1]`. Whoops. This might produce a garbage value or cause a crash (or anything else).

By the way, `a` is redundant here--just use `i` to get the index (having to resort to `a` to get the index smells like something is off). The `arr[i - 1]` trick might have been done to compensate for another bug:

```
while (cc_num != 0)
{
    cc_num /= 10;
    arr[digits] = cc_num % 10;
    digits++;
}
```

The problem here is that `cc_num /= 10;` says "move on to the next digit". But this skips the first digit completely. This should be:

```
while (cc_num != 0)
{
    arr[digits] = cc_num % 10;
    digits++;
    cc_num /= 10;
}
```

---

Another problem which can be identified by turning on warnings is

```
ARRAY WITHOUT LINE BREAKS: -1747166688
```

Here, the compiler tells us the problem:

```
$ clang-7 -o main main.c
main.c:67:49: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the
      argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
    printf("\n\nARRAY WITHOUT LINE BREAKS: %i", arr);
                                           ~~   ^~~
1 warning generated.
```

To dump the array's values, use a loop and print each element individually.

---

Other remarks:

1. Invalid user entries cause an infinite loop.
2. Good job breaking things into functions, but try to avoid side effects in functions, especially printing. For example `num_of_ccdigits` does quite a lot more than simply getting the number of credit card digits. It also does validation and I/O. If you remove the print statements and make it responsible for purely counting the digits in a number, you can rename it `count_digits(long long int num)` and make it reusable on any `long long int`. Then, handle printing and validation elsewhere, say, `print_digits(long long int num)` and `validate_cc_digit_length(long long int num)`. Check out [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
3. I'm a bit confused by the purpose of the function

   ```
   void payment_method()
   {
       int num_of_digits = num_of_ccdigits();
   }
   ```

   Function names are typically actions, describing what the function does, rather than nouns, which are typically variables. Consider something like `get_payment_method()`.

   Also, since `num_of_ccdigits` calls itself recursively on bad data, it can potentially cause the stack to overflow. Using a `while` loop is a better way to handle bad input that can go on unbounded.
4. For initialization like:

   ```
   int digits = 0, arr[MAX_CRED_LEN];
   ```

   prefer:

   ```
   int digits = 0; 
   int arr[MAX_CRED_LEN];
   ```

   which is easier to read.

Comment: This definitely answered my question I have a much better comprehension as to what I did and how to fix it. I see what you mean with the function `num_of_ccdigits()` I was having problems and that is how that extra code ended up there, the intentions for that function was just to be a digit counter like you had mentioned thanks for the quick reply.